# TS: Boolean for for loop equals true on line before, still won't run

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop, boolean

This function to label inside of a range using a for loop will not run the logic inside the for loop at all. Previously, I was defining the arguments for the for loop more dynamically, using indexing, and it was consuming all of my memory running a multimillion length loop. Completely unsure how this loop is not running.

```
      selectMonth(newMonth: number) {
        console.log(newMonth);
        const NMH: number[] = [ 744, 1416, 2160, 2800, 3624, 4344, 5088, 5832, 6552, 7296, 8016];
        const WH: number = 168;
        let labelValue: Label[] = ['Sunday'];
        // let i = NMH[newMonth];
        let WC = 0;
        let loopSize = NMH[newMonth + 1] - NMH[newMonth];
        console.log(" loopSize" , loopSize);
        let i = 0;
        console.log("i right before" , i, i < loopSize)
        for(i; i++; i < loopSize) {
          console.log("inside loop" , i)
        }
        console.log(labelValue);
  }
```

[console print out of this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNfFF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap conditional statement `i < loopSize` and step `i++`.

```
      selectMonth(newMonth: number) {
        console.log(newMonth);
        const NMH: number[] = [ 744, 1416, 2160, 2800, 3624, 4344, 5088, 5832, 6552, 7296, 8016];
        const WH: number = 168;
        let labelValue: Label[] = ['Sunday'];
        // let i = NMH[newMonth];
        let WC = 0;
        let loopSize = NMH[newMonth + 1] - NMH[newMonth];
        console.log(" loopSize" , loopSize);
        let i = 0;
        console.log("i right before" , i, i < loopSize)
        for(i; i < loopSize;i++) {
          console.log("inside loop" , i)
        }
        console.log(labelValue);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, just caught this looking at my other functions doing the same thing. Just started my morning coffee haha

Thank you for the patient answer!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the arguments are flipped around. For loop should be initiated with:

```
for(i; i++; i < loopSize) {
```

There are some dumb questions haha

Comment: The code you posted here is the same as your original code - it still has the statements  in the wrong order.